# ASP.NET Error:The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have no JQuery or other javascript changing values or html-structure. And I have no controls that is added dynamically.

Still I get the error: **The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted**

The error occurs somewhat random. Here is how I can replicate the issue, aspx-file:

```
<%@ Page ViewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" MaxPageStateFieldLength="40" ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeFile="tbTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>tbTest </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button id="Submit1" type="submit"  
        runat="server" onClick="btnclick_Click" Text="Submit" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbStatus" enableViewState="true" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width="617px" Height="67px" ReadOnly="True" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.cs-file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                tbStatus.Text = timestamp.ToString() + ". Page Loaded. ";
            }catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            } catch (Exception ex){
            } 
        }    
    }

    protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            tbStatus.Text += Environment.NewLine + timestamp.ToString() + ". TextBox updated. ";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            tbStatus.Text += Environment.NewLine + timestamp.ToString() + ". Error. " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This really gives me head-ache. After 3-4 submits the error is there. I have tested changing values for **ViewStateEncryptionMode, MaxPageStateFieldLength, ValidateRequest, AutoEventWireup** and  **EnableEventValidation** without success.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the enableEventValidation attribute in the web.config file for the asp.net application to false.

might also need to check
http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2007/11/one-possible-reason-for-the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-exception/

And

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;829743

IIS compression enabled on IIS6 can also cause this.  Verify this is turned off.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why, but saving the viewState in the session solved it!:
    `protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() 
    { 
         return Session["_ViewState"]; 
    }
 
    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState) 
    { 
         Session["_ViewState"] = viewState; 
    }`

Comment: Downvoted for just suggesting to turn off event validation.  This is not an acceptable response in most business cases.

Comment: @ctb3 well said. In most business cases but not in all cases.

Comment: In general you still want validation for every page except whichever one is having problems.

Comment: Plarsen, thank you! That solved my issue with working on session variables and passing custom callbacks with Dev Express proprietary grid view controls. Making sure the viewstate was saved got around this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had searched many pages and finally this is working for me

```
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() 
{ 
return Session["_ViewState"]; 
}
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState) 
{ 
Session["_ViewState"] = viewState; 
}
```

Comment: This method fixed the following exception when nothing else I tried would:

    Inner Exception: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 

   Inner Exception: Invalid viewstate.

Just be careful to use a page-specific key for our Session object and warn or prevent users from opening multiple instances of your page.  All instances will share the same viewstate unless you hide a unique key in a hidden input tag.

Comment: @Bhaumik Brahmbhatt where theses methods will go and how to use it, does it need to be added on each page or Global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue without errors in the code. What helped me out was to restart the asp.net session state service:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in webconfig in system.web  tag solved my problem.

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" validateRequest="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added these 3 lines in the `web.config` file, and now it is working fine for me.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="3000" />
<pages enableSessionState="false" /> 
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Answer (score -4):

remove if you have 
 `<div><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="#" /></div>`
in masterpage